# Monoalphatic and Polialphabetic cipher in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, functional-programming, caesar-cipher

This code encrypts a text with  mono-alphabetic and poli-alphabetic substitutions ciphers.

For further info see:

- [Mono-alphabetic/Caesar Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)
- [Poli-alphabetic cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyalphabetic_cipher)

```
require 'arrow_test'

ALPHABET = ("a".."z").to_a

# Moves a letter forward in the alphabet by
# the given key wrapping around.
#
# <code> 
# shift('a', 2) #=> 'c' 
# </code>
#
# <code> 
# shift('z', 2) #=> 'b' 
# </code>

def shift(letter, key)
  ALPHABET[ (ALPHABET.index(letter) + key) % ALPHABET.length]
end

# Encrypts a text using by shifting all its letters by
# the given key. All characters that are not lower and alphabetic
# are deleted.
# 
# <code>
# monoalphabetic_cipher('abcd', 2) #=> 'cdef'
# </code>
# 
# <code>
# monoalphabetic_cipher('cdef', 2, decode=true) #=> 'abcd'
# </code>

def monoalphabetic_cipher(text, key, decode=false)
  text
      .chars
      .select { |char| ALPHABET.include?(char) }
      .map {|char| shift(char, (decode ? 26 - key : key) )}
      .join
end

# Given a word, returns the positions of its letters
# in the aplhabet.
#
# <code>
# word_to_alphabetic_positions('abcz') #=> [0, 1, 2, 25]
# </code>

def word_to_alphabetic_positions(word)
  word.chars.map {|char| ALPHABET.index(char) }
end

# Encrypts a text by <code>shift</code>ing each letter by
# the amount specified by the corresponding key number,
# wraps around over the key if the plain text is longer than it.
#
# <code>
# polialphabetic_cipher('abcd', [1,3,4,0]) #=> 'begd'
# </code>
#
# <code>
# polialphabetic_cipher('begd', [1,3,4,0], false, decode=true) #=> 'abcd'
# </code>

def polialphabetic_cipher(text, keys, keys_as_word=false, decode=false)
  keys = word_to_alphabetic_positions(keys) if keys_as_word
  text
      .chars
      .select { |char| ALPHABET.include?(char) }
      .each_with_index
      .map do |char, index|
        key = keys[index % keys.length]
        shift(char, (decode ? 26 - key : key))
      end
      .join
end

arrow_test
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Extract constant expression to outside of loop

In this code, `(decode ? 26 - key : key)` is evaluated for each character in `text`:

> ```
>   text
>       .chars
>       .select { |char| ALPHABET.include?(char) }
>       .map {|char| shift(char, (decode ? 26 - key : key) )}
>       .join
> ```

It would be better to move it outside the expression so that it's only evaluated once:

```
  shift_key = decode ? 26 - key : key

  text
      .chars
      .select { |char| ALPHABET.include?(char) }
      .map {|char| shift(char, shift_key)}
      .join
```

#### Minor formatting issues

The code formatting style is not consistent, for example compare these two lines:

> ```
>       .select { |char| ALPHABET.include?(char) }
>       .map {|char| shift(char, shift_key)}
> ```

In the first one, there's a space after `{` and before `}`,
but in the second there isn't.
Both ways seem fine to me,
but it would be better to use one of these ways, consistently everywhere.

Similarly here,
there's a space after `[` but not before `]`.
For the sake of consistency,
it would be better to remove the space after `[` or add one before `]`.

> ```
>   ALPHABET[ (ALPHABET.index(letter) + key) % ALPHABET.length]
> ```

#### Overall

This looks nice, a pleasure to read, and I don't even know Ruby ;-)

Comment: _Extract constant expression to outside of loop_ works only in the mono-alphabetic cipher, in the poli-alphabetic one the key is not a loop invariant

Comment: Oops, my bad, dropped that point

Comment: Ruby is a very nice language, I enjoy programming in it. You may be interested in [Functional Programming in Ruby](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming) that webpage shortly explains the basics of effective ruby usage.